# Analytics framework for windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, analytics

Does Microsoft have analytics framework for  Windows Phone 8.1 similar to Google Analytics? I know there are libraries for Google Analytics on Windows Phone but I wonder of Microsoft has its own analytics framework.

Answer (score 0):

There is [Application Insights](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-windows-monitor-usage-crashes/) (requires Azure account) by Microsoft that can also be used in Windows Phone and Windows Store apps.